# Search in API and Display API

Tags: json, search

How to search that any keywords

I have two different blocks of code but I dont know how i can combine it

The things that i want is when you search in second box it will display like first coding. I dont mind if got button not.

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <title>JSON/Atom Custom Search API Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="content">
            <input type="text" id="Query">
            <button id="add">Search</button>
        </div>

        <script>
         function hndlr(response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
            var item = response.items[i];

            // in production code, item.htmlTitle should have the HTML entities escaped.
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML +="<br>"+"<b>"+ item.title + "</b>"+"<br>" +item.snippet  + "<br>"+"<a href='"+item.link+"'>"+item.displayLink+"</a>" ;

        }
    }
        </script>

        <script id="fixme"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var search_query = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Query&cx=004123968310343535430%3Aaxml6iel9yo&key=AIzaSyDxPcphnrcN9_dfkRkFTbwkv44m1-HI1Hg&callback=hndlr';
        document.getElementById('fixme').src = search_query;
    </script>

    <script>
    function showHint(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) { 
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q="+str+"&cx=004123968310343535430%3Aaxml6iel9yo&key=AIzaSyDxPcphnrcN9_dfkRkFTbwkv44m1-HI1Hg&callback=hndlr", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p><b></b></p>
    <form> 
    <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    </form>
    <p>Answer <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

For more details

```
http://mediamonitoring.comyr.com/jquery3.php
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to help out with the AJAX call and `onkeyup` trigger? It wraps around things like `XMLHttpRequest` and provides a much cleaner, more flexible calling method [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Also avoids the `document.getElementById` chaff: `$('#fixme').attr('src', search_query)` for example.

Comment: So do u have any solution for this?

Comment: I try using this code after u told me, but i got underfined

$(function(){

  var $tutor = $('#tutor');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=unimap&cx=004123968310343535430%3Aaxml6iel9yo&key=AIzaSyDxPcphnrcN9_dfkRkFTbwkv44m1-HI1Hg',
    success: function hd(tutor) {
      
      $.each(tutor,function(i,item){//the new item is returned with an ID
       
            $tutor.append('<li>Name:'+item.htmlTitle+', Age '+item.displaylink+'</li>');
               
      });
    }
    
  });
});

Comment: It's generally better to edit your question and add additional code like that, comments make it really hard if not impossible to read. That does look better, mind you.

Comment: I already solve this question by making another function but i got another problem. Hope u can solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558232/refresh-javacript-src

Comment: If it's solved, it's best to answer it with what you did, share that with others, or delete it so nobody ends up answering it and duplicating your work.